# NextAuth session access token wrong

Tags: jwt, youtube-api, next.js, google-signin, next-auth

I'm trying to implement NextAuth with the Google Provider to make requests using the Youtube Data API. However, when using the session callback, the access token seems to be wrong as I'm unable to make any requests with that token. When using the JWT callback, the access token seems to be the correct one. Did anybody experience this? I would like to use the session callback but have not found a way to get the same access token that a JWT callback would give me.

Edit 1:
Not sure if this will help as it is more of a general question about whether NextAuth's session access token and JWT access token are different but here's the callback option:

```
const callbacks = {
 async session(session, user) {
    // Add property to session, like an access_token from a provider.
    const data = await fetch(
         `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?access_token=${user.accessToken}&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%2Cid&mine=true`,
         {
             method: 'GET'
         }
    );

    const response = await data.json();
    
    const newSession = user;
    newSession.accessToken = session.accessToken;
    newSession.expires = session.expires;
    newSession.channelName = response.items[0].snippet.title;
    newSession.channelId = response.items[0].id;

    return newSession;
 }
}
```

And here's the response using the session access token:

```
{
  error: {
    code: 403,
    message: 'The request is missing a valid API key.',
    errors: [ [Object] ],
    status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED'
  }
}
```

With the JWT access token I get the right results.

Comment: Some code and an example and the actual API response would help your question get responses.

Comment: I suspect that `user.accessToken` is undefined when you get the error you've shown.